# I can't log into my local copy of Magento -- how to use lost password with local copy of software?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, mamp

I have a local install of Magento on my Mac using MAMP. I need to retrieve my password, but the lost password is obviously not working out of the box.

Is there a way with MAMP to use the lost password feature (e.g. by activating a mail sever)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The default login is : admin The
>   default password is : 123123
>
> If you are having troubles and want to
>   reset it to a different password, just
>   run at your sql database:
>
> `SELECT * FROM admin_user;`
>
> Then, find
>   the username you want to modify in the
>   listing provided - 'admin' in this
>   example. Then, to update the password,
>   type:
>
> `UPDATE admin_user SET
>   password=CONCAT(MD5('qXpassword'),
>   ':qX') WHERE username='admin';`
>
> 'qX'
>   would be changed to whatever you want
>   it to be and same goes for 'password'
>
> You can also do this in phpMyAdmin,
>   find the admin_user field and choose
>   MD5 when updating password.

[Source](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/resetting-admin-password)

Comment: Please quote the relevant parts of a link when it contains an answer. The site could go down / change contents, making the link stale and the answer lost.

Comment: I've done the above and successfully changed the password, but it's still not letting me lot into a local copy of Magento. I also tried accessing the site using the local ip (127.0.0.1:8888) rather than localhost, but that's not solving the problem. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a dirty fix courtesy of [Rick Torres](http://php.quicoto.com/cant-log-in-magento-admin/) which worked for me...

Open file...
/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php

Around line 100 you will find...

```
call_user_func_array('session_set_cookie_params', $cookieParams);
```

Comment it out like this...

```
//call_user_func_array('session_set_cookie_params', $cookieParams);
```

And you're done.

Bear in mind that hacking core files like this is not ideal as when you update to a newer version of Magento this file may be overwritten. Also remember to uncomment the line when you move the site to a live server ;)