# Magento Local install - admin password doesn't work

Tags: magento, installation, mamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't log into my local copy of Magento — how to use lost password with local copy of software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631270/i-cant-log-into-my-local-copy-of-magento-how-to-use-lost-password-with-local)

I installed a local copy of Magneto on my Mac using MAMP. I have tried this several times, but the login/password combo doesn't work. Any ideas what might be going on?

Here are the (important) settings on the Magento config:

host: localhost:8888
baseurl: http://127.0.0.1/magento
Skip Base URL validation

Comment: I also reset the password manually using PHPmyAdmin (including an MD5 hash) and using a mix of letters/numbers in the password. The local version still isn't letting me in...

Comment: if you have problem following the instructions for an earlier question, post your comment on THAT question, don't open a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you aren't trying to access the site via http://localhost as Magento has an issue with domains that don't have a DOT in them.  Instead, use http://127.0.0.1 or use a real domain pointed at your local IP.  You will need to update the core_config_data table to reflect the hostname you want to access Magento from.

Comment: What is the required update exactly? Thanks.

Comment: Update the base_url for secure and unsecure URLs.  Or do the install using http://127.0.0.1

Comment: Thanks, I found another way, it is actually working in firefox.